# nginx not passing requests to unicorn.sock

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app with Mina. Nginx returns the default page. Unicorn stderr.log has to 2 workers ready. Why is nginx not putting requests in the unicorn.sock file?

```
upstream app {
    # path to unicorn SOCK file
    server unix:/home/deployer/APP/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
 }

server {
    listen *:80 default_server;

    root /home/deployer/APP/current/public;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app;
    }
}
```

http://blog.mccartie.com/2014/08/28/digital-ocean.html is the tutorial I used.

How can I get this working? Thanks.

EDIT: Unicorn.rb

```
# Set your full path to application.
app_dir = File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)
shared_dir = File.expand_path('../../../shared/', __FILE__)

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30

# Fill path to your app
working_directory app_dir

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Loging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/pids/unicorn.pid"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{app_dir}/Gemfile"
end
```

Comment: How are you configuring unicorn? Is there a unicorn.rb in the config directory of your rails app? Can you share the config?

Comment: @MarcusWalser Unicorn.rb has been added.

Comment: Can the user running nginx write to the socket file?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?